# Get values of WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory from custom TFS activity

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Using the following custom TFS activity I am attempting to get the sources directory from the WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory.  However, it always returns null.  How can I get the value of WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory from within the C# code of a custom activity (I don't want to pass the value in)?

```
public class MyActivity : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var eve = new EnvironmentVariableExtension();
        var sourcesDirectory = eve.GetEnvironmentVariable<string>(context, WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory);
    }
}
```

I also tried this which returns null as well...

```
public class MyActivity : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var sourcesDirectory = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is EnvironmentVariableExtension?

Comment: I think it's new for TFS2013.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.activities.extensions.environmentvariableextension.aspx

Comment: Got the same issue. If I'm not mistaken the "dir env:" powershell command should include all these new TF_BUILD_* variables added by TFS2013, in my case these are missing. I'll try to manually add them and see what happens. Maybe it's just a configuration issue caused by the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a value of an environment variable from your code, just use something like this:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY")
```

Full list of TFS Build related environment variables can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh850448.aspx#program_or_script

Comment: Are you sure your build server is running TFS 2013 and you are using the new build template: TfvcTemplate.12.xaml ?

Comment: Correct, 2013, and the default build template which has been modified to run our custom TFS activity.

Comment: Are you using "Default Template" which is the old 2012 template that doesn't use environment variables, or the new "TfvcTemplate.12.xaml" which is the 2013 template that uses environment variables instead of workflow variables.

Comment: Using the Default Template whose filename is TfvsTemplate.12.xaml.